# Google Forms - Campo Hidden

Tags: javascript, formulário, google

Através do Google Script, consigo deixar um campo visível se for selecionado uma determinada opção em outro campo ?

Comment: Pode ser respondido utilizando apenas os recursos já presentes do Google Forms?

Comment: Eu fiz através da opção que existe no radio button. Onde eu direciono a partir de uma escolha.

Mas o que eu queria, era tudo na mesma página. Sem precisar ficar alternando.